# QT 5.0.2 everywhere opensource configuration error on linux

Tags: qt, configuration

A very simple question.
I am building qt under linux(CentOS to be exact), and I've been having trouble migrating from QT 4.8.4 to QT 5.0.2.

The current configuration for QT 4.8.4(and also want it the same in 5.0.2) is

```
./configure $QTCONFARGS -confirm-license -release -no-phonon -no-webkit -no-multimedia -no-sql-odbc -prefix
```

On 5.0.2, I get errors on no phonon, no webkit, and no multimedia.
I read the help for configurations, and I found none of these.
Question is, what the equivalent of these three cofigurations?

Comment: does [this](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git) help?

Answer (score 1):

See [this page](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-5-from-Git) from Qt documentation. Note that

- Phonon was dropped in Qt 5.
- The option to leave webkit out is `--no-webkit` (note double dashes) in *init-repository* and `-no-webkit` in *configure* (only single dash).
- To skip multimedia, use `--no-multimedia` or `-no-multimedia` similarly to above.

Comment: I just tried it. On the help for configuration, I don't see any option to leave out webkit or multimedia, and so it fails. Thank you for letting me know Phonon was dropped in Qt5.